# Given two sets, one is closed and contains the other, can I find another closed set that contains one of the sets and is included in the other?

Tags: general-topology

I have two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\subset B$ and $A$ is closed. Can I find a closed set $C$ such that $A\subset C\subseteq B$? We can discuss the following two cases separately:

- $B$ is closed
- $B$ is open
- $B$ is arbitrary

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For clarification, are you using $\subset$ to refer to $\subsetneq$, a proper subset but unequal?  Do you mean for $C$ to be a proper subset of $B$ as well, otherwise what is stopping you from letting $C=B$?  Is $B$ closed?  Your title says "given two closed sets" but you make no mention of $B$ being closed in your body.  Also, in what topology are you working?

Comment: Your title implies $B$ is closed while the text does not guarantee it.  As the text is written if $B$ is closed you can take $C=B$

Comment: It is true for metric spaces. It is not true in general (For example take $\{0,1\}$ with the trivial topology, $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\{0\}$.)

Comment: @JMoravitz $\subset$ refers to a proper subset. I want to discuss all the possibility of $B$ being open or closed (i have edited my question). Thanks!

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks for pointing this out. What about the case of $B$ being open?

Comment: @Yanko would you please clarify your answer more? I am not an expert in topology. My two sets are subsets of an Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: you have edited your question, so my answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following topology on $\mathbb R$,

{$\emptyset, \mathbb R, [0,1], [0,1]^c$}

If we take $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[0,1] \cup \{5\}$

Then we cannot find closed set $C$ satisfying your condition.

Comment: thanks! What if my sets are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You mean ${\mathbb R}^n$ with standard topology?

Comment: In ${\mathbb R}^n$ with standard topology you can always find such set $C$ as you can always take $C=A \cup \{x\}$ where $x \in B-A$